# About the front-end route of history mode intercepting routes configured by nginx

Tags: vue.js, nginx, frontend, nginx-reverse-proxy

My vue project is configured with history mode, but at this time I need to configure a / login to do rewrite to [www.sso.com](http://www.sso.com) in the current domain name, because I need to jump to different sso single sign-on addresses according to different domain names.
The problem now is that when I visit my project and add / login to my domain name, I can't take the rewrite information configured by nginx, but is directly routed to the front end and jumps to the front end 404 page.